# stash {exp:stash:set} and {exp:stash:set_list}

Tags: stash

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="about"}
{exp:stash:set name="page_meta_description"}{about_meta_description}{/exp:stash:set}                
{exp:stash:set name="page_meta_keyword"}{about_meta_keyword}{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:set_list name="about" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Possible set stash and set stash list with 1 channel entry tag? like mention above.
currently i seperate it to 2 entry tag, cause above one won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible, I do it all the time.  Can't really tell much from yor example though as you're not setting anything inside the list itself.  Can you post a more complete example?